# Выделение и удаление памяти в JNI

Tags: jni, java, c, c++

Предположим, есть библиотека на C или C++. В этой библиотеке выделяется и удаляется память. Есть ли способ отслеживать использование памяти в библиотеке извне средствами Java? Или не средствами Java?

Comment: Эта библиотека подгружена к JVM?

Comment: Да.

Comment: А каким образом она выделяется? Через обычный malloc?

Answer (score 1):

Объявите Java-объект, который взаимодействует с JNI-кодом [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), подчистите все ресурсы в методе `close()`, и в документации строго напишите, что метод `close()` вызывать обязательно после окончания работы. Это нормальный сценарий для освобождения сторонних ресурсов в Java (так работают, например, `FileOutputStream`, SQL-выражения и так далее).

Answer (score 0):

Касательно native функций в Java я недавно перечитывал Брюса Эккеля
Thinking in Java 4ed. Автор рекомендует переопределять метод finalize()
и выполнять в нём очистку памяти для native кода.
Эта функция может (!) быть вызвана Garbage Collector'ом при необходимости,
- например, когда приложению станет не хватать памяти.

Для чистого java кода использовать finalize() нет необходимости.

Comment: Это очень устаревший способ. Использование finalize уже давно не рекомендуется. Использовать такое следует только в крайних случаях, когда иначе невозможно.

Answer (score -2):

Как мне кажется, нет. Можно с помощью C#. Там это называется небезопасным кодом. А в Java такова нет.